# Why my Cloudwatch SEARCH expression stopped returning data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using [getMetricData](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-data.html) and the following expression to get the CPU Utilization of all the instances I had:

`SEARCH('{AWS/EC2,InstanceId} MetricName="CPUUtilization"', 'Average', 3600)`

My instances were terminated around 15 days ago. This was working. But now, I'm not getting data anymore.

Are metrics supposed to being retained for 15 months? I don't see them in the AWS cloudwatch console either.

Answer (score 0):

This is true if the data is still being added to CloudWatch. However the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/faqs/) states that if no data is pushed you will lose the data after 2 weeks.

> CloudWatch console limits the search of metrics to 2 weeks after a metric is last ingested to ensure that the most up to date instances are shown in your namespace.

Comment: Thanks. But that is only for the console, isn't? My understanding is that I can still get the metrics through the cloudwatch API.

Comment: That is correct, from the docs it does say this. I wonder if search expressions abide by the same rules as the console. I would raise to AWS support as there is no specific mention in the documentation